# Sailsjs socket.io not working locally

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

I have a weird problem with a sails v0.10.0 app.  Socket.io works perfectly fine on one local environment (using sails memory adapter) and I've successfully got it working in heroku as well (using the redis adapter).

However in another local dev environment, the socket never seems to connect.  The log from sails lift --verbose just says:

```
verbose: A socket.io client (xjrJf2WexeZi2BqbdKVv) connected successfully!
verbose: set close timeout for client xjrJf2WexeZi2BqbdKVv
verbose: socket error Error: read ECONNRESET
at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
at TCP.onread (net.js:558:19)
```

Even after switching socket adapters from memory to a local redis server, I get the same error.

Other things I've tried are:

- npm cache clean, reinstall packages
- manually installing [sails.io.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/blob/8f6bee080ebe1547acfdb3f52714e37f4eebf753/README.md) package
- I know about the socket syntax change in sails 0.10.0 and have upgraded the code (works perfectly fine in another local env).

Anyone have an idea with what is going on here or how I can get some better debug information?

**EDIT**

Just realized something fails during `npm install sails@beta -g`.  I get a build error:

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options

> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\Miano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Users\Miano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
```

And unfortunately I can't seem to find any builderror.log.

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue?  Is this is just a vanilla app with a client doing a socket connection to a Sails server on localhost?

Comment: Yes, issue still persists. And yes this happens on a vanilla sails new project.

Comment: However I did notice something new during npm install sails.  I've updated my question.